# How to use Python3 multiprocessing to append list?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, list, numpy, multiprocessing

I have an empty list `empty_list = []` 
and 2 other lists: `list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`,`list2=[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]`.

I would like to two things:

1. I would like to pick up `[1,2,3]` from list and `[10,11,12]` to make `[1,2,3,10,11,12]`;`[4,5,6]`and`[13,14,15]` to form `[4,5,6,13,14,15]` and finally `[7,8,9],[17,18,19]` to form `[7,8,9,17,18,19]`
2. append `listA=[1,2,3,10,11,12]`, `listB=[4,5,6,13,14,15]`, `listC=[7,8,9,17,18,19]` to empty with `axis=0`.

I have done this work by non-multiprocess but slowly. I would ask how to do it by multiprocess.
I have two naive approaches but do not know how to implement it.

1. to use pool,

   make a `func0`, for picking up sub-lists and merge them using `pool.map(func0,[lst for lst in[ list1,list2,list3]]`

   make a `func1` for appending `listA, listB, listC` to the empty  and then `pool.map(func1,[lst for lst in [listA,listB,listC]])`,
2. to use `multiprocessing.Array`
   but I have not figured out how to do it

This sample may not need to use multiprocessing but I have lists with thousands lines.

Comment: Are you sure you need multiprocessing? Some code optimization could be enough

Comment: I have much larger files

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help, but you can avoid some list comprehensions:

```
empty_list=[]
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    empty_list.append(l1+l2)
```

Let's check time performance with some random lists:

```
import timeit
code_to_test = """
import numpy as np
list1 = [np.random.randint(0,10, 100).tolist() for i in range(10_000)]
list2 = [np.random.randint(0,10, 100).tolist() for i in range(10_000)]

empty_list=[]
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    empty_list.append(l1+l2)
"""
elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=100)/100
print(elapsed_time, ' seconds')
0.12564824399999452 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have done this with similar code with non-multiprocessing.

Comment: Alright, I am not an expert in multiprocessing, not sure how to help from here onwards. Maybe I will try to learn it :)

Comment: You should just time starting with `empy_list` or `[l1+l2 for l1,l2 in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: I have lots files with huge lines.multi-processing is necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dask` to parallelize numpy operations:

```
import dask.array as da
list1 = da.from_array(list1)
list2 = da.from_array(list2)

result = da.hstack([list1,list2])
result.compute()
```

Comment: Thanks for  more suggestions. If this code can be carried out simultaneously  by different processes, that would be nice.

Comment: @Lawrence edited my answer to avoid making a third one. If you want to use numpy syntax/functions in a parallelized way, I think dask is what you can use.

Comment: I just checked out dask. That would be amazing for my future work, distribution wokflow. I just worked out a little bit last night using multiprocessing. I will let you know when I finish. By the way do you know how to carry out zip() by multiprocessing?

Comment: I don't really know. However if you are happy with that answer you should accept it.